# Check value against values in array and return key using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, comparison, logic

**Problem:**

I have a value that is set in $record, for instance 1.69. Then I have an array that contain different grades and values. I would like to compare $record against the highest value first to see if it is higher or equal to, if not go to the value below it, and so forth.

**PHP code:**

```
$record1 = '1.69';
$record2 = '2.90';
$record3 = '3.40';
$record4 = '3.80';
```

**Array ($grades):**

```
Array
(
    [G] => 2.8
    [VG] => 3.8
)
```

**Scenario:**

$record1 should be compared to the highest value in the array, this will return false. It will compare to the value below the highest value, which also will return false. If both return false then return the string 'U', otherwise return the key G or VG.

- Record 1 should produce U.
- Record 2 should produce G.
- Record 3 should produce G.
- Record 4 should produce VG.

**Question:**

I could do a lot of if-statements as a solution but I wonder if there is any clever way of doing this check in a better way?

Comment: How many record variables are there?

Comment: +1 for clearly defining the problem. Do you have the ability to create a `$record` array instead of independent variables?

Comment: There's always only going to be 1 $record variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple logic:

```
$grades  = array('G' => 2.8, 'VG' => 3.8);
$records = array(1.69, 2.9, 3.4, 3.8);

foreach ($records as $v) {
    $res = ($v < $grades['G'] ? 'U' : ($v < $grades['VG'] ? 'G' : 'VG'));
    echo "$v = $res\n";
}

/*
1.69 = U
2.9 = G
3.4 = G
3.8 = VG
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that loops through your `$grades` array, sets the value of the result and breaks as soon as the value is bigger than the input.

Something like this (untested):

```
function returnGrade($record, $grades)
{
  $return = 'U';
  foreach  ($grades as $key => $value)
  {
    if ($record >= $value)
    {
      $return = $key;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try and sort the array in descending order.

Then, in a while loop, check if the initial array element (use [key()](https://www.php.net/key) function) is bigger or smaller, if FALSE, use [next()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) function to move to next element and compare that.

The loop should end when your desired comparison returns TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way

first rotate in loop by number of records and check that value is in array or not by this function `in_array()`

if result found then get key by this function `array_search("value_to_search","array_variable");`

Hope this will helpful to you